# users.isAppUser in new Graph API

Tags: graph, facebook-fql

Can we call equivalent of users.isAppUser via the new Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering to this old post because I'm working on ways to make users.isAppUser work.

As of April 13th, 2011, this is taken from the users.isAppUser page on the Facebook developers site:

> Please note: We are in the process of
>   deprecating the REST API, and will be
>   adding equivalent support to the Graph
>   API for this method. You should
>   continue to use this method until we
>   announce support in the Graph API.

So, the Graph API does not have the equivalent for users.isAppUser, **for now.**